# Union all not returning data

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have this below query not returning results, but both select statements are returning results separately. Also if both where clause are removed, the union query does return the data. I can't tell what I'm missing.

```
select col1, col2, col3 , 'A' AS type from table1 where col4 = 'A'

union all

select col1, col2, col3, 'B' AS type from table1 where col5 = 'B'
```

In the above query table1 is a common table expression defined prior to this statement.

Comment: I know that, I just wanted to make my post simple and leave the note about what table1 is. When I run the query, the WITH statement part that defines table 1 is included

Comment: Can you provide a sample set of rows for `table1` that reproduces the situation? I'm wondering whether there's some elements in your original query that are attaching to the wrong SELECT, and it might be fixed by putting parentheses around the individual SELECT queries?

Answer (score 2):

Or, you could simply use:

```sql
SELECT
  col1,
  col2,
  col3,
  CASE WHEN col4 = 'A' THEN col4
       WHEN col5 = 'B' THEN col5
       END as type
FROM table1
WHERE col4 = 'A' OR col5 = 'B'
```

This will only show each row once, whereas your query might have shown the same row multiple times if `col4 = 'A' AND col5 = 'B'`.

Comment: I forget to mention that I have tried it before with the case statement I saw result, but I wanted to get to the bottom of why the union is not returning results. And for this use case same row returned multiple times is not a concern.